# Why is the this.$on() callback triggered upon mount of a component?

Tags: vue.js, vue-component

I have a component which `$emit` to its parent upon some activity.

The parent listens to this event and triggers a function upon reception. This is assembled in `mount()`:

```
<template>
    <v-app>
        <v-toolbar fixed app>
            <v-toolbar-title v-text="title"></v-toolbar-title>
            <v-spacer></v-spacer>
            <v-btn color="error" dark large>Large Button</v-btn>
        </v-toolbar>
        <v-content>
            <new-case v-on:dirty="updateDirty"></new-case>
        </v-content>
        <v-footer app>
            <span>&copy; 2017</span> dirty: {{dirty}}
        </v-footer>
    </v-app>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        data() {
            return {
                case: {
                    id: null,
                    title: null,
                },
                cases: [],
                title: 'Vuetify.js',
                dirty: false,
            }
        },
        watch: {
            dirty: () => {
                console.log('requesting relaod of data')
            }
        },
        methods: {
            updateDirty(what) {
                console.log('requesting update of dirty state '+what)
                this.dirty = what
            }
        },
        mounted() {
            this.$on('dirty', this.updateDirty())
        }
    }
</script>
```

The whole mechanism works fine (the emmited even is correctly handled by the parent), except that when the component is mounted, I see in the console

```
17:36:01.380 App.vue?ea99:36 requesting update of dirty state undefined
17:36:01.449 App.vue?ea99:31 requesting relaod of data
17:36:01.561 backend.js:1  vue-devtools  Detected Vue v2.5.13
```

**Why is `this.updateDirty()` triggered upon the mount of the component?** (even though nothing was emitted yet - not only the component which would emit something is not used yet, but the DevTools Vue panel does not show any events yet)

Comment: Try `this.$on('dirty', this.updateDirty)` instead. You're likely executing the method when you're setting the event listener, when you should really just be passing a reference to the function or method you want. If this doesn't work, consider showing us your `new-case` code as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is with you $on call itself. The parenthesis after updateDirty, `this.$on('dirty', this.updateDirty())`, is the culprit, it is telling JS to run the function and store the result as the event handler. Try `this.$on('dirty', this.updateDirty)` instead so you're passing the reference to the function not the result.

Comment: Thank you. One thing I still do not understand is why, in that case, further emitted events are correctly handled (i;e., they trigger the callback). Since *"[the parenthesis] run the function store the result as the event handler"* , shouldn't that result be "triggered" (whatever that would mean) upon a received event? Today the callback function is stilled called as the handler (instead of its result, which is `null` as nothing is explicitly returned)